# Xcode DATE text macro not performing as expected

Tags: xcode

I’m not sure if this is really an ask, but I thought I’d try anyway.

I’m trying to format a file name so that it shows the date in its title. Sound easy, right?

I can’t use the ***DATE*** text macro, however, because the / creates new folder paths (which would be great if the dates were in a different order than they are but... what can you do).

However, when I try to use a modifier (as specified by Apple), the format ‘eats’ the first number.

I’m in my phone right now so I can’t show results but an example:

Template for the file’s name:

```
HelloWorld-___DATE:bundleIdentifier___.swift
```

What I expect:

```
HelloWorld-29-03-2019.swift
```

What I am getting:

```
HelloWorld--9-03-2019.swift
```

Any ideas what’s going on or should I just take the L?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `bundleIdentifier` modifier on a date? What happens if you remove the modifier?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Removing the `bundleIdentifier` modifier causes the file to create folders for every `/` in the date. So the file would just be `2019.swift`, nested in a `HelloWord29/03` path. 

(Rewritten so I could properly tag)